# Relative paths in package.json?

Tags: json, npm, gulp, browserify

I've got a project where `src/main/webapp/com/mycompany/frontend/page/index.js` depends on `target/webjars/log4javascript/1.4.10/log4javascript.js`.

I've added `package.json` alongside `index.js` with the following contents:

```
{
    "browser":
        {
            "log4javascript": "../../../../../../../target/webjars/log4javascript/1.4.10/log4javascript.js"
        }
}
```

I've got many other dependencies in the `target` directory. Is there a way for me to avoid repeating `../../../../../../../target/` for every dependency?

Comment: `index.js` and `log4javascript.js` are in project directory? Or `log4javascript.js` outside?

Comment: When you say you have many other dependencies, you mean other files that you'd add to the `browser` field, or you mean files that `log4javascript.js` `require()`s?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

Answer (score 2):

One option is to put the directory that contains your local modules, or a symlink to it, in `node_modules`, such as `node_modules/app` and then reference your requires as `app/...`, e.g. I believe this would work

```
{
    "browser":
        {
            "log4javascript": "app/target/webjars/log4javascript/1.4.10/log4javascript.js"
        }
}
```

Or you could structure it however you want, e.g. `node_modules/log4javascript` (which, if you have symlinks, could point to `/whatever/target/webjars/log4javascript`).

This makes it so that `require()` will find it in the same fashion as npm modules, without publishing it to npm. The main drawback to this is that it breaks the ability to programatically configure transforms, e.g. with `browserify('app/entry').transform(whatever)`, `app/entry` and other files in the dependency graph that are under `node_modules` will not have the transform applied to them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the section *Using Non-Relative Paths* in [this article](http://aeflash.com/2014-03/a-year-with-browserify.html).

You can use grunt-browserify's aliasMapping option to specify the root of your app:

```
aliasMappings: [{
  cwd: 'src',
  dest: 'myApp',
  src: ['**/*.js']
}]
```

and then you can directly refer to everything from the root path, without having to ever use any  dreaded `../`'s:

```
require("myApp/target/webjars/log4javascript/1.4.10/log4javascript.js")
```

Of course, this doesn't resolve the problem that it's still a very long path.

The article's next paragraph makes a very good point: if you're calling things way over at the other end of your application like that, it's a good sign that things may not be correctly architected.

Can you split the functionality into smaller modules? Perhaps make log4javascript its own module?

---

Add to my answer, from discussion below:

If log4javascript is in your package.json file as a browser (non-NPM) module, you should just be able to require it with `require('log4javascript')`

Comment: log4javascript is an example of a non-npm library, which is why I am referencing it as a local file. How would I make it "its own module" without publishing it to npm? Also, I forgot to mention: I need this solution to work for `gulp`.

Comment: Here's how to use non-NPM libraries as modules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061040/how-to-use-browserify-with-non-npm-libraries

Comment: I already know that (since I posted that question). That solution works, but doesn't solve the problem with relative paths.

Comment: Ha, didn't notice that you asked that question. However, I'm confused as to why it doesn't answer your question. Once you have the module named "log4javascript" in your package.json, you can just require it with `require('log4javascript')` and browserify will find it. Doesn't that solve your long-path issue?

Comment: No, it does not. I am trying to avoid long paths in `package.json`, not just the `require()` statement.

Comment: Ahhh... I totally leapt to the assumption that you were talking about require paths. My complete mistake. I guess I've just never seen a project where the package.json file wasn't at the root of the project. It seems very odd to have it all the way up in a nested folder. But I'm sure there are reasons...